# $.ajax post to a ruby on rails 4.1 nested resource is resulting in route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to post to a nested resource using $.ajax post.
Not sure what is that I am missing. Appreciate your help!

Here is my

***routes.rb***

```
resources :clients do
     resources :timesheets
end
```

rake routes output:

```
autocomplete_client_name_clients GET      /clients/autocomplete_client_name(.:format)       clients#autocomplete_client_name
                   client_timesheets GET      /clients/:client_id/timesheets(.:format)          timesheets#index
                                     POST     /clients/:client_id/timesheets(.:format)          timesheets#create
                new_client_timesheet GET      /clients/:client_id/timesheets/new(.:format)      timesheets#new
               edit_client_timesheet GET      /clients/:client_id/timesheets/:id/edit(.:format) timesheets#edit
                    client_timesheet GET      /clients/:client_id/timesheets/:id(.:format)      timesheets#show
                                     PATCH    /clients/:client_id/timesheets/:id(.:format)      timesheets#update
                                     PUT      /clients/:client_id/timesheets/:id(.:format)      timesheets#update
                                     DELETE   /clients/:client_id/timesheets/:id(.:format)      timesheets#destroy
                             clients GET      /clients(.:format)                                clients#index
                                     POST     /clients(.:format)                                clients#create
                          new_client GET      /clients/new(.:format)                            clients#new
                         edit_client GET      /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                       clients#edit
                              client GET      /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#show
                                     PATCH    /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                                     PUT      /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#update
                                     DELETE   /clients/:id(.:format)                            clients#destroy
```

Here is the client jquery code that does the post to the server:

```
return $("#save_timesheet").click(function() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "<%= client_timesheet_url @timesheet.client, @timesheet %>",
      data: {
        timesheet_data: {
          name: "Filip",
          description: "whatever",
        }
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data.id);
        return false;
      },
      error: function(data) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

The server side url helper

```
<%= client_timesheet_url @timesheet.client, @timesheet %>
```

out puts similar to this:

```
/clients/2/timesheets/44
```

On the server side this results in an error as below:

```
Started POST "/clients/2/timesheets/44" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-08 18:27:58 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/clients/2/timesheets/44"):
```

Here is the detailed server log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/clients/2/timesheets/44"):
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.2) lib/quiet_assets.rb:18:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: "rake routes".. output please

Comment: Try running ```rake routes``` to make sure your path matches one of the routes.

Comment: also I think,<%= client_timesheet_url @timesheet.client %> this should help

Comment: rake routes output added

Comment: change `type: "post"` to `type: "put"`

Comment: @BroiSatse, wow! that was it. Would you mind entering it as an answer so that I can mark it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no route matching this url with POST verb, you should use PUT instead:

```
type: "put",
```